# javascript associative arrays width while

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, while-loop, associative-array

i have a problem width this simple code...
I created an associative array width a while cycle that should be constituted of four elements...
the problem is that it works only width the first two elements : matrice[1][1] and matrice[1][2]...
not width matrice[2][1] and matrice[2][2]
thanks in advice!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td id='0'>
            <td id='1'>
        <tr>
            <td id='2'>
            <td id='3'>
    </table>
    <script>
    var a = 1;
    var b = 1;
    var c = 0;
    var matrice = new Array();
    while (a <= 2){
        matrice[a] = {};
        while (b <= 2){
            matrice[a][b] = Math.random();
            document.getElementById(c).innerHTML = matrice[a][b];
            c++;
            b++;
        }
        a++;
    }
    document.write(matrice[2][2]);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: don't use document.write with  document.getElementById(). in fact, don't use document.write at all for this.

Comment: matrice[0][1] and matrice[0][2] should contain the other elements ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set varibale b to 1 again:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
var c = 0;
var matrice = new Array();
while (a <= 2){
    matrice[a] = {};
    while (b <= 2){
        matrice[a][b] = Math.random();
        //document.getElementById(c).innerHTML = matrice[a][b];
        c++;
        b++;
    }
    a++;
    b = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 1, b = 1, c = 0, matrice = [];

while (a <= 2){
  matrice[a] = {};
  while (b <= 2){
    matrice[a][b] = Math.random();
    document.getElementById(c).innerHTML = matrice[a][b];
    c++;
    b++;
  }
  a++;
  // don't forget to reset b
  b = 1;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td id='0'>
        <td id='1'>
    <tr>
        <td id='2'>
        <td id='3'>
</table>
```